# How to make a long oval shape with custom shadow in Android

Tags: android, xml

I think i mentioned the name of the shape wrong.

I want to make shape like the following image with shadows in Android,

[Sample model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYcLs.png)

So how to make this type of layout in Android .

thanx for the help!!

Comment: https://slothdevelopers.wordpress.com/2014/05/22/shadow-effect-with-custom-shapes/

Answer (score 0):

You should try this one:

https://github.com/Hitomis/CrazyShadow

By drawable you can generate the shape, and by using this library you will be able to add shadow.

Or: 
You can use the library itself.